# Multiple Textures on one UV? or multiple UVs? (Large Mesh)

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

I seriously need some guidance. Iv'e spent hours on google and came up short.
I am simply trying to texture a building I've modeled with many different textures (the different colors represent different textures). One version of the building is a single object, while another version is split up into walls which are primitives. **What would be a good method to acheive the fully textured building?**
I should add, this model is meant as part of a video game level.
[image: One object]

[image: Multiple walls]

Everything I do, nothing lines up.

Comment: What game engine are you using?

Comment: Im using Unreal

Comment: Well coming up with a single non repeating huge texture covering that large amount of wall surface seems unpractical and unoptimal in terms of performance. A seamless tileable texture would seem to be the answer, though game engines do tend to dislike multiple materials per mesh. Probably break it apart into different materials, either way you should only need one UV map, I think, unless you plan on baking some sort of lighting, shadows, or ambient occlusion.

Comment: Only workflow Ive found to somewhat work is to take every wall parallel to each other and combine into one mesh so 4 objects total for the 4 sides of the building. Then I select only the faces I want from one of the objects and go into orthographic and to the front view one of the objects adjacently. Then I project UV from current location and bam, a perfectly draw to scale UV. Repeat for rest of materials.

Comment: I would use a "trim sheet" for that. Basically, one huge texture divided into many seamless textures covering the different materials and details (like cables, grids etc). It's efficient cause the engine have one big texture to load instead of many small (and if you use a PBR workflow, one material instead of many). You'll found some great examples on Google Images.